# Did Imam Bukhari and Imam Muslim believe in Sahih hadiths that are not in their compilations?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Did Imam Bukhari and Imam Muslim ever believe in Sahih hadiths that they did not put in their compilations? If they did, then why didn't they include them in their compilations?

Comment: Isn't this already addressed in [What exactly are the conditions of al-Bukhari and Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/what-exactly-are-the-conditions-of-al-bukhari-and-muslim?rq=1)

Comment: No, this doesn't answer my question. I want to know if Imam Bukhari might've believed in authentic hadiths that he didn't put in his compilation and the same for Muslim. If not, does that mean that the hadiths in Sahih Bukhari are the only Sahih hadiths Imam Bukhari believed in or did he believe in other sahih hadiths? The same line of questioning for Imam Muslim as well.

Comment: The third paragraph of the answer in the linked duplicate addresses this, read from: "Third, not all that is authentic is compiled in these two books ..." it gives quotes of Bukhari and Muslim.

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! They did believe in some reliable hadith that they did not include in their compilations.

Bukhari says:

> "What I have included in my book "Al-Jama'i al-Sahih" is correct, but **there are many reliable hadiths that I did not quote in order to make my book longer**."

Muslim bin Hajjaj Qashiri says:

> "**I have not included all the reliable hadiths in the "Sahih" book,** but I have tried to mention only the hadiths that are unanimous."

---

[Reference](https://hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/65621/%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AB-%D9%85%D9%87%D8%AF%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85) by hawzah.net

Comment: Is there a book that contains all the hadiths that were excluded from Sahih Bukhari that Al-Bukhari thought were authentic?